# iOS 14.2 Beta - AVPlayer Cannot Play

Tags: ios, avplayer, ios14, xcode12

Apple has made a significant AVFoundation change in iOS 14.2 beta from iOS 14.0 (Now Playing Control Center UI change and etc).

The problem is that a simple audio AVPlayer app that worked perfectly in iOS 14.0 does not work in iOS 14.2 Beta 2 anymore.

In iOS 14.2 Beta 2, users are greeted with "Cannot complete action" error, and the playback does not start.

Did anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: @matt, can we reopen this question as I have removed Apple's planning part from my question?

Comment: It would just be closed again as lacking details needed to reproduce. Please see [ask] and add a [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe reporting this problem to Apple could help with an official answer.

I had problems with iOS 14.2 Beta 2 on real devices but not on simulator. I was able to fix it for me by setting `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = YES`

With `NO` i run into

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11819 "Cannot Complete Action" UserInfo={NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try again later., NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot Complete Action, NSUnderlyingError=0x280e34d80 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-17221 "(null)"}}

Comment: `automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling` did the trick. I believe this is a iOS 14.2 beta bug.

Comment: @MacMark - I'm also able to see same issue... only audio playing, no video on iOS 14.2