# AVPlayer Cannot Play in iOS 14.2 Beta

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation, avplayer, ios14

Apple has made a significant AVFoundation change in iOS 14.2 beta from iOS 14.0 (Now Playing Control Center UI change and etc).

The problem is that a simple audio AVPlayer app that worked perfectly in iOS 14.0 does not work in iOS 14.2 Beta 2 anymore.

In iOS 14.2 Beta 2, users are greeted with "Cannot complete action" error, and the playback does not start.

Did anyone found a workaround for this issue?

Comment: Identical to your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205425/ios-14-2-beta-avplayer-cannot-play. It was closed. You don't get to just ask it again to work around the closure. Improve the question and try to get it reopened.